Coin disappeared from Phantom wallet
A coin straight up disappeared from my phantom wallet, i still see it in solscan but i cant see it in the phantom wallet.
I tried checking if it was disabled in the bottom but its not even there, I keep refreshing and nothing, anyone know what to do or what happened?
